# .htaccess rules for accessing subdirectory as document root

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using Magento on a LAMP stack.

I have my primary store/application accessible from the root directory (e.g. website.com/). I have created a custom form for processing 3rd party vouchers at ***website.com/redeem/index.php*** or just ***website.com/redeem/***. I will not be using the default landing/home page of Magento that is found at website.com/. Instead I would like visitors to visit the site and have htaccess load the contents of /redeem - the URL would not change from website.com

I still need to access my admin panel which is located at website.com/admin (the full version being website.com/index.php/admin).

Is it possible to achieve this with redirects? I also thought about redefining the index of my root directory to /redeem/index.php but I'm not sure if that is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Does Magento use the RewriteEngine in Apache? If not, you can easily redirect the root path to a subdirectory. If it does, you can still use Rewrite rules, but they will be slightly more complex. (If it does use RewriteEngine, can you provide the rules here?)

Comment: Yes, it does in fact use the rewrite engine.